# UICollectionView inside an UITableView does not respond to user interaction

Tags: ios, user-interface, storyboard

I have an `UICollectionView` inside the `contentView` of the cell of an `UITableView`. I cannot furnish UI code since it is handled by a Storyboard.

Sadly, the callback `- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` of my delegate is never called when the user tap on one of the cell of the collection view. Note that it seems that my delegate have been assigned with success since other delegate methods are indeed called.

I tried the following without success:

- Disabling the user interaction in all the parent view of the collection view;
- Doing the same for the subview of the collection view's cell; and
- Using an `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the collection view's cell instead of the delegate. callback.

Note: my collection view is dynamically resized.

Comment: which delegate methods are being called on your collection view?

Comment: `- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` is called during layout but the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`isn't when one taps.

Comment: what is inside your collection view cells? It might be their contents affecting the delegate call back

Comment: An image view and a label.